# How to merge two columns in join query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tow tables

table 1

```
id |   name   |  birthdate
1  | 'sylvie' |  2016-06-01
2  | 'rolf'   |  -
3  | 'jose'   |  2004-02-16
4  | 'Eugin'  |  -
5  | 'andrey' |  1998-09-29
6  | 'ivan'   |  2000-05-12
7  | 'vasiys' |  2001-07-17
8  | 'alexey' |  1993-09-05
```

Table 2

```
id |   name   | date_of_birth
1  | 'sylvie' |  -
2  | 'rolf'   |  2015-12-06
3  | 'jose'   |  -
4  | 'Eugin'  |  1995-04-01
5  | 'andrey' |  1998-09-29
```

if i run this query :

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.birthdate, t2.date_of_birth from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id --(or using(id))
```

the result is

```
id |   name   |  birthdate   | date_of_birth
1  | 'sylvie' |  2016-06-01  | -
2  | 'rolf'   |  -           | 2015-12-06
3  | 'jose'   |  2004-02-16  | - 
4  | 'Eugin'  |  -           | 1995-04-01
5  | 'andrey' |  1998-09-29  | 1998-09-29
6  | 'ivan'   |  2000-05-12  | -
7  | 'vasiys' |  2001-07-17  | -
8  | 'alexey' |  1993-09-05  | -
```

but I need a table that combine the both columns birthdate from table1 and date_of_birth from table1.
the result should be like that:

```
id |   name   |  birth_date
1  | 'sylvie' |  2016-06-01  
2  | 'rolf'   |  2015-12-06 
3  | 'jose'   |  2004-02-16
4  | 'Eugin'  |  1995-04-01
5  | 'andrey' |  1998-09-29 
6  | 'ivan'   |  2000-05-12
7  | 'vasiys' |  2001-07-17 
8  | 'alexey' |  1993-09-05
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a full outer join here:

```sql
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name,
       coalesce(t1.birthdate, t2.date_of_birth) as birthdate
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
order by coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)
```